# cannot make debouncetime to work with an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to when user finish writing in input box make the request, i have tried with debounceTime so it can make a 3 seconds delay before making the query but i don't know how to implement in my case, most examples with rxjs are in the component but not in a service call. Thanks

//HTML

```
 <input _ngcontent-juw-c105="" placeholder="Buscar" type="text" id="edit-combine" name="searchFilter" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" class="caja_texto form-text form-control lupa ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" style="width: 100%;" ng-reflect-maxlength="128" ng-reflect-name="combine" [ngModel]='titulo' (keyup)='setFiltered()'>
```

//Component

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.tituloSub = this.valueChanged
      .pipe(debounceTime(3000))
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.setFiltered();
      });
  }

  setFiltered() {
    this.loader = true;
        this.buscadorService.getNodes()
        .subscribe((data: InformesCounter) => {
          this.loader = false;
          this.buscadorService.pageNumber = this.page;
          this.informesNode = data.data;
          this.nid = this.informesNode.map((data: { id: any;}) => data.id);
          console.log("test");
          this.nodeList = this.informesNode.map((data: { attributes: any;}) => data.attributes);
          this.showResolucion();
          this.showInforme();
          this.showFicha();
          this.showDifusion();
      });
  }
```

//Service

```
  getNodes(): Observable<InformesCounter> {
    this.pageNumber = 1;
    return this.http.get<InformesCounter>(`${this.informesNodes}`); //myuri is in informesNodes
  }
```

Comment: probably because the service is not the correct place to debounce. Do it in the component.

Comment: I'm doing the debounce in the component not in the service, the service only bring me the interface and the http request.

Comment: it is a little confusing what you have there, you have both keyup calling setFiltered and a subscription calling it as well. So your set filtered would be called through the key up, and depending how you implemented the valueChange, then it would  call it again after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so your on the right track, but you need to make a few changes, create a subject, which will be subscribed with debounce time, and calls the search method. Then in the `keyup or change` event you can call the `next` method of the `subject` which will be recieved in the subscribe we wrote earlier and finally perform the search if the debounce time condition is met!

html

```
<input
  placeholder="Search"
  [(ngModel)]="searchStr"
  (ngModelChange)="triggerSearch()"
/>
```

ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {
  filter,
  debounceTime,
  distinctUntilChanged,
  tap,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  searchSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  searchStr = '';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // server-side search
    this.searchSubject.pipe(debounceTime(1500)).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('do the action here for the value: ', this.searchStr);
    });
  }

  triggerSearch() {
    this.searchSubject.next();
  }
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-debounce-search-field-vnp3su)

Comment: Works with console.log but when i do the .subscribe((data: InformesCounter) => {} it returns no result... i'm trying to figure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: The problem is in the service call this.buscadorService.getNodes(); i dont know how to implement with subject.

Comment: Solved i put the function inside the subscribe and i separated the two suscriptions inside two different functions.